# pd.dataframe saving only one line

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, arraylist, semantic-segmentation

Hi i'm wondering what should i do to save all those values in a dataframe...

```
for mask in range (len(predicted_masks)):
  folha = np.where(predicted_masks [mask,:,:] == 1 , 1, 0)
  soma_folha = np.sum(folha)
  sintoma = np.where(predicted_masks [mask,:,:] == 2 , 1, 0)
  soma_sintoma = np.sum(sintoma)
  fundo = np.where(predicted_masks [mask,:,:] == 0 , 1, 0)
  soma_fundo = np.sum(fundo)
  #print(soma_fundo, soma_folha, soma_sintoma)
  severidade = (soma_sintoma/(soma_folha+soma_sintoma))*100
  severidade = round(severidade,2)
  print(soma_fundo, soma_folha, soma_sintoma, severidade)

  d = {'mask': mask, 'soma_folha':soma_folha, 'soma_sintoma':soma_sintoma, 'soma_fundo':soma_fundo, 'severidade': severidade}
  df = pd.DataFrame([d])
  df.to_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/DB_mosca_minadora/pred_csv/pred_test_db_anotated.csv', index=False)
```

already tried to save each one separately but it wont came up..

i needed to save all printed values in a dataframe, thats for 304 images (304 lines) buts it only saves the last line

[image]

can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting and saving your dataframe within the loop. You should instead do something like the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['mask', 'soma_folha', 'soma_sintoma', 'soma_fundo', 'severidade'])

for mask in range (len(predicted_masks)):
  folha = np.where(predicted_masks [mask,:,:] == 1 , 1, 0)
  soma_folha = np.sum(folha)
  sintoma = np.where(predicted_masks [mask,:,:] == 2 , 1, 0)
  soma_sintoma = np.sum(sintoma)
  fundo = np.where(predicted_masks [mask,:,:] == 0 , 1, 0)
  soma_fundo = np.sum(fundo)
  #print(soma_fundo, soma_folha, soma_sintoma)
  severidade = (soma_sintoma/(soma_folha+soma_sintoma))*100
  severidade = round(severidade,2)
  print(soma_fundo, soma_folha, soma_sintoma, severidade)

  d = {'mask': mask, 'soma_folha':soma_folha, 'soma_sintoma':soma_sintoma, 'soma_fundo':soma_fundo, 'severidade': severidade}
  new_df = pd.DataFrame([d])
  df = pd.concat([df, new_df])
df.to_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/DB_mosca_minadora/pred_csv/pred_test_db_anotated.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: thank u so much, very appreciated