# Save lists as rows of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I am new to pandas. I hope this is not too easy :). I have tried to solve this problem without success.

I am using beatifulsoup to scrape a website. My variable gets the result I am looking for.

```
var = [sd.get_text() for sd in x.select("li")]
```

The variable contains this output:

```
var =
[A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H]
[I, J, K, L, M, M, N, O, P]
[Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X]
```

I add what this variable prints by request of comments:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
['I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P']
['Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X']
```

In addition, I have the title of the columns:

```
columns = ["Element1", "Element2", "Element3", "Element4", "Element5", "Element6", "Element7", "Element8"]
```

I want to store each list collected in the variable as a row in my Dataframe. I think I have to iterate over the variable with a for loop to do this, but I'm not sure.

The result I'm looking for is this:

| Element1 | Element2 | Element3 | Element4 | Element5 | Element6 | Element7 | Element8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H |
| I | J | K | L | M | N | O | P |
| Q | R | S | T | U | V | W | X |

Thanks!

---

### Result

Finally, I was able to solve the problem.

I have passed my var variable to a new list containing only one column.

```
list_columns = ["1"]
df = pd.DataFrame(newvar, columns=list_columns)
split_df = pd.DataFrame(df['1'].tolist(), columns = ["Element1", "Element2", "Element3", "Element4", "Element5", "Element6", "Element7", "Element8"])
split_df.to_csv('element.csv', index=False)
```

In this way I managed to store all the data with the correct columns.

Thanks @Mortz for the help!

Comment: When you say you have a variable that contains the output - what type of variable is that? Is it a string? A list of lists?

Comment: Hi @Mortz. yes, my variable is a list containing lists

Comment: can you try to print(var), because to be honest I still confused by your input var, and your problem still not solved yet

Comment: Hi @d_frEak. I have updated the question with what you have requested

Comment: with that input, actually @Mortz solution should have works and you just need to df.to_csv(filename, index=False) to print it into a csv file. for debugging, you can try to print(df) before print it into file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your variable to a list of lists and pass it to a DataFrame constructor -

```py
myvar = [[A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H],
[I, J, K, L, M, M, N, O, P],
[Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X]]

df = pd.DataFrame(myvar, columns=columns)
```

Comment: I have tried this. If I now screen print the myvar variable this is the result:
`[[A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H]]
[[I, J, K, L, M, M, N, O, P]]
[[Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X]]`
Instead, when I use `df.to_csv('document.csv')` to pass this to a csv document, only the first list is logged. How can I fix this?

Comment: You mean that the file `document.csv` only contains one row, i.e. - `A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H` ?

Comment: Exactly, I can't get all the rows to be stored, one in each row of the document. I have updated the question to try to give some more information. @Mortz

Comment: I try with this `df = pd.DataFrame([mybar], columns=list_columns)` before saving to csv, but I can't get the correct result.

Comment: I can't think how I can reproduce the issue - can you create a minimal, reproducible example? For example,  pick up a few `li` items from a "public" website and then convert that to a csv? You can then share the entire code (including the scraping bit)

Comment: I have replicated exactly the problem I have with this code https://pastebin.com/GkBT0hUY. I get the same thing when I try to save to a csv. Only the first list is saved. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi @Mortz. I have done some research. I found this question. I think it may be related to the problem I have with saving. Unfortunately, I cannot adapt it to my example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70932810/pd-dataframe-saving-only-one-line

Answer (score 2):

not sure how the first variable is stored

I will assume text:

```
data = '''
[A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H]
[I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P]
[Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X]'''
```

added data cleaning step:

```
import re
data = re.sub(r'\[|\]', ' ', data)
```

to df:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), names=columns)
```